# Grab values from row if cell[X] has written input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Hello everyone right now I'm trying to retrieve informatmion inside a table, I currently have this example in order to retrieve all the row values if `value="!= null"`, but if I remove the attribute `value=""` in my inputs I can't grab the information I type inside the inputs

```html
    <table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="tableID">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>A</th>
          <th>B</th>
          <th>C</th>
          <th>D</th>
          <th>E</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">val1</td>
          <td align="center">val2</td>
          <td align="center">val3</td>
          <td align="center">1500</td>
          <td align="center" class="myID"><input type="number" name="txtID" class="txtID" value="123"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">val1</td>
          <td align="center">val2</td>
          <td align="center">val3</td>
          <td align="center">1500</td>
          <td align="center" class="myID"><input type="number" name="txtID" class="txtID"  value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">val1</td>
          <td align="center">val2</td>
          <td align="center">val3</td>
          <td align="center">1500</td>
          <td align="center" class="myID"><input type="number" name="txtID" class="txtID"  value=""></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <button onclick="aplicar()">Aplicar</button>
    <script>

    </script>

    <script>
    function aplicar(){
        var myTab = document.querySelectorAll('#tableID tbody tr .txtID:not([value=""])');
        var tableData = [];
        Array.from(myTab).forEach(input => {
          var tds = input.closest('tr').children;
          var obj = {};
          obj.A = tds[0].textContent;
          obj.B = tds[1].textContent;
          obj.C = tds[2].textContent;
          obj.D = tds[3].textContent;
          obj.E = input.value;
          tableData.push(obj);
        });
        console.log(tableData);
    }
    </script>
```

This will input the first row data because it has `123` value inside, but I need to remove the value attribute and get the data I type inside the input.

I will post this information using AJAX at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the *value* attribute on *input* event:

```js
function setValueAttr(el){
  el.setAttribute('value', el.value)
}

function aplicar(){
    var myTab = document.querySelectorAll('#tableID tbody tr .txtID:not([value=""])');
    var tableData = [];
    Array.from(myTab).forEach(input => {
      var tds = input.closest('tr').children;
      var obj = {};
      obj.A = tds[0].textContent;
      obj.B = tds[1].textContent;
      obj.C = tds[2].textContent;
      obj.D = tds[3].textContent;
      obj.E = input.value;
      tableData.push(obj);
    });
    console.log(tableData);
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="tableID">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">val1</td>
      <td align="center">val2</td>
      <td align="center">val3</td>
      <td align="center">1500</td>
      <td align="center" class="myID"><input type="number" name="txtID" class="txtID" oninput="setValueAttr(this)" value="123"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">val1</td>
      <td align="center">val2</td>
      <td align="center">val3</td>
      <td align="center">1500</td>
      <td align="center" class="myID"><input type="number" name="txtID" class="txtID" oninput="setValueAttr(this)"  value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">val1</td>
      <td align="center">val2</td>
      <td align="center">val3</td>
      <td align="center">1500</td>
      <td align="center" class="myID"><input type="number" name="txtID" class="txtID" oninput="setValueAttr(this)"  value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="aplicar()">Aplicar</button>
```

**OR:** You can directly check the value of the element with *if* condition

```js
function aplicar(){
    var myTab = document.querySelectorAll('.txtID');
    var tableData = [];
    Array.from(myTab).forEach(input => { 
      if(input.value.trim() != ""){
        var tds = input.closest('tr').children;
        var obj = {};
        obj.A = tds[0].textContent;
        obj.B = tds[1].textContent;
        obj.C = tds[2].textContent;
        obj.D = tds[3].textContent;
        obj.E = input.value;
        tableData.push(obj);
      }
    });
    console.log(tableData);
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="tableID">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">val1</td>
      <td align="center">val2</td>
      <td align="center">val3</td>
      <td align="center">1500</td>
      <td align="center" class="myID"><input type="number" name="txtID" class="txtID" value="123"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">val1</td>
      <td align="center">val2</td>
      <td align="center">val3</td>
      <td align="center">1500</td>
      <td align="center" class="myID"><input type="number" name="txtID" class="txtID"  value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">val1</td>
      <td align="center">val2</td>
      <td align="center">val3</td>
      <td align="center">1500</td>
      <td align="center" class="myID"><input type="number" name="txtID" class="txtID"  value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="aplicar()">Aplicar</button>
```

Comment: Mamun can you please recommend me any resource you think would be good enough to learn javascript? I really need some direction Mr Mamun

Comment: @IceeFrog, working and learning is the best way, there are lot of helpful resources available, you can refer https://javascript.info/